# Selenium, id tags change on reload (python)

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to get selenium to click the "Edit" button, which is on the right of the "File" button.  I would use a simple find_by_id, but the "id" changes on every page reload.  I'm wondering if there is a way to do this.

Here is the button I'm looking for:

```
<button id="eIGMd-b" type="button" class="z-menu-btn">Edit&nbsp;</button>
```

Here is the "File" button before "Edit":

```
<button id="eIGM7-b" type="button" class="z-menu-btn">File&nbsp;</button>
```

Now if I look up the xpath after stipping out the ID tags I get something like this:

```
/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/button
```

I'm thinking I need to use "find_element_by_xpath" but my syntax is way off. Any suggestions on how I should go about doing this?

I would include all the code for the page but It's too much and a mess. Also turning off the dynamic id tags is not an option.

Comment: You should be able to use what's in the link above to handcraft an XPath that looks for a BUTTON that contains "Edit", "File", etc.

Comment: I got it to work using     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Edit')]]").click()

Comment: I would make it more specific (add `button`) and you had some unnecessary stuff in there, `"//button[contains(.,'Edit')]‌​"`.